# Failure to import module in python

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to use the twisted.mail package in Python:

```
root@beagleboard:~/twisted# ls /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/mail/
__init__.py       imap4.pyo         pop3client.py     smtp.py
__init__.pyo      mail.py           pop3client.pyo    smtp.pyo
_version.py       mail.pyo          protocols.py      tap.py
_version.pyo      maildir.py        protocols.pyo     tap.pyo
alias.py          maildir.pyo       relay.py          test
alias.pyo         pb.py             relay.pyo         topfiles
bounce.py         pb.pyo            relaymanager.py
bounce.pyo        pop3.py           relaymanager.pyo
imap4.py          pop3.pyo          scripts
```

I have twisted.mail installed, and within it is a module called imap4. twisted/mail contains the magic **init**.py file which makes it a python module.

so i should be able to import from it:

```
root@beagleboard:~/twisted# python
>>> from twisted.mail import imap4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named twisted.mail
```

As you can see, I'm doing this on a Beagleboard running Angstrom, but that shouldn't matter, should it? However, I can do exactly the same thing on my Ubuntu 11.10 and it imports fine.

I have verified that I do not have a twisted.py module in my current directory.

What silly mistake am I making?

Comment: That looks like the error you'd get if twisted weren't installed.  First few things to verify: (1) `which python`, to make sure it's the one you think it is; (2) print sys.path; (3) import twisted; print twisted (in case I'm wrong about whether it's finding it.)

Comment: Great ideas, and thanks for your quick reply. Here are the answers, somewhat edited to fit:

Comment: # which python
    /usr/bin/python
    # python
    Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 25 2011, 16:50:01) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload']
>>> import twisted
>>> print twisted
<module 'twisted' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/__init__.pyo'>

Comment: Hmm.  That looks right, unfortunately.  Could it be a permissions issue?  (I note that you were in /home/root, which is an unusual place to be running user code from.)  This is also the error message you'd get if the files existed but you didn't have permission to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the package that you're attempting to import. Go up one level first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply: # pwd
/home/root